# What happens if ARP does not find an associated IP

Tags: networking, protocols, arp

I understand the basics of how ARP works, one host sends out a MAC Broadcast with "Who has this IP?" and some host in the network answers with "I have that IP".

But what happens if a Router is connected to the same LAN, the routers function would be to connect the LAN to the WAN (hope I got that right). Does the host asking for the adress then automatically switch and send a message to the connected router with his data or what happens?

Comment: This question is better suited to https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is, that your IP stack first determines to where it needs to send the packet to. If it goes to an IP address that is in a directly connected network, it will send the packet directly, otherwise, it will send the packet to the gateway.

This may sound abstract to you. For a simple case, suppose you have the following network:

```
     host_a        host_b
 +----------+   +----------+
 |10.1.1.101|   |10.1.1.102|
 +-----+----+   +-----+----+                           
       |              |           +--------+         <--------->
  -----+--------------+-----------+10.1.1.1|--------<  INTERNET >
                                  +--------+         <--------->
                                   Router
```

On your host_a, you will have

- ip address 10.1.1.101
- netmask 255.255.255.0
- default gateway 10.1.1.1

On your host_b, you will have

- ip address 10.1.1.102
- netmask 255.255.255.0
- default gateway 10.1.1.1

Suppose host_a wants to send a packet to 10.1.1.102. If you use the IP address and netmask, you see that it is in the same subnet. So, host_a will send an ARP-request onto the network asking "Hey, who has 10.1.1.102?" Host_b will respond with its MAC-ID.

Now suppose host_a wants to send to 8.8.8.8. That is not on the local network. So, host_a will now send it to its default gateway, 10.1.1.1. Host_a will send an ARP-request "Hey, who has 10.1.1.1?" and the router will respond with its MAC-ID.

The procedure above is a great simplification of what actually happens, but it may help you a step further in how your network works.

(the question may be more appropriate for another SE site, but then someone will probably migrate it)

Comment: Great explanation thank you